# Does a Rails plugin exist to build a show page (like a formbuilder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a Rails plugin providing a builder for `show.html.erb` pages.

For example, with SimpleForm, an `new.html.erb` page might look like this :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => user_registration_path, :html => ... }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But I was not able to find an equivalent for just displaying fields.

A generated `show.html.erb` page looks like :

```
<p>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>
...
```

But I'd like something like :

```
<%= simple_display_for(@user, :html => ... }) do |d| %>
  <%= d.output :email %>
  <%= d.output :name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Does this kind of builder exist?

Thanks

**EDIT** : If the builder use Twitter Bootstrap, that's even better :)

Comment: Check out [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper). It provides an easy way to add Presenters to your application, and you can use it to create a few simple helper methods to get the exact DSL you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any gems, but here is a simple example of how to build this feature yourself, which you can expand on:

**lib/simple_output.rb**

```
class SimpleOutput
  def initialize(resource)
    @resource = resource
  end

  def output(attribute)
    @resource.send attribute
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/simple_output.rb**

```
require_dependency 'lib/simple_output'
```

**helpers/simple_output_helper.rb**

```
module SimpleOutputHelper
  def simple_output_for(resource, options={}, &block)
    content_tag :div, yield(SimpleOutput.new(resource)), options[:html] || {}
  end
end
```

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_output_for(@user, html: { style: "background-color: #dedede" }) do |r| %>
  <%= r.output :name %>
  <%= r.output :email %>
<% end %>
```

Now, obviously this is just a very simple example, but hopefully it will get you started on the right track. Look at the simple_form source to see how they organize their code, and how they "typecast" fields. The simple_form codebase is very clean and easy-to-follow Ruby, and is a great example of what a gem should look like.

Comment: thanks, that's a very useful snippet ; not sure if I have to accept it since that's not really answering my question...

Comment: Give a man a fish... ;) Don't worry about it, I just posted it as an answer because it was too long to post as a comment. I think my comment (about [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper)) is actually closer to an answer.